# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 Parse Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have issues with parse data base.

When i want to send data to data base, i got such type of error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Console:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z83UA.jpg)

I have no idea whats is wrong, i have lot of data which i need send to data base, but i cant.

My code:

```
func sendDataToServer() {
    do {
        
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt")
        let source = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: path!)
        var elements = source?.components(separatedBy: "\n\n") // Here is the change
        var parsedObject = [[String: String]]()
        
        for i in 0..<(elements?.count)! - 1 {
            let objects = [String : String]()
            let element = elements![i]
            
            let objectsElement = element.components(separatedBy: "\n") // And Here
        
            if objectsElement.count > 1 {

                let question = objectsElement[0]
                let answer1 = objectsElement[1]
                let answer2 = objectsElement[2]
                let answer3 = objectsElement[3]
                let answer4 = objectsElement[4]
                let answer5 = objectsElement[5]
               
                let array = ["\(answer1)","\(answer2)","\(answer3)","\(answer4)","\(answer5)"]
              let result = array.shuffled()
                
                let ans1 = result[0]
                let ans2 = result[1]
                let ans3 = result[2]
                let ans4 = result[3]
                let ans5 = result[4]
                print(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5)
                
                let addDatasToDB = PFObject(className: "testBase")// creating name table
                addDatasToDB["question"] =  question // send data from loaded txt file
                addDatasToDB["answer1"] = ans1
                addDatasToDB["answer2"] = ans2
                addDatasToDB["answer3"] = ans3
                addDatasToDB["answer4"] = ans4
                addDatasToDB["answer5"] = ans5
                parsedObject.append(objects)
                addDatasToDB.saveEventually { (success, error) in
                    self.count += 1
                   
                    if success {
          print("------->successfuly saved \(self.count)")
                    }
                    else {
                        print(error!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: post json and how you decode it

Comment: I don't use JSON

Comment: May you please share your data.txt file content. Also do you know witch line number fails?

Comment: @Husein Behboodi Rad data.txt it's list with question and answers, code are not fails, at image you can see, some times it's send some data. But not all.

Comment: Maybe there are some problem in you data. It can be useful to check the data. Also as I understood some times you may face runtime error and your try will catch the error. Did you checked witch line of the code cause the error and firing the catch block?

Comment: *I don't use JSON*. This might explain the error  The error is related to `JSONSerialization`. And you are encouraged to use a more sophisticated text format than simple plain text line separated.

Comment: @Husein Behboodi Rad i think about this, but i try send data to server which i send before, before it was sending (same data i send two times), but now i got this error